# Phalcon PHP dispatcher forward does not work

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm following [this official tutorial](https://vimeo.com/63022489) to learn [phalcon](/questions/tagged/phalcon) framework version **2.0.9**.

I have a `voteAction` of the `PollController` the following code supposed to redirect or forward to `showAction` after increment `number_votes` as follows:

```
public function voteAction($optionId)
{
    $option = PollOptions::findFirstById($optionId);
    $option->number_votes++;
    $option->save();
    return $this->dispatcher->forward([                
        'action' => 'show',
        'params' => [$option->poll_id]
    ]);
}
```

However, after voting the I have got `poll/vote/xx` not `poll/show/yy`, *where xx is the option id and yy is the poll is respectively*.

I have tried to add `'controller' => 'poll'` and replacing `[]` array definition by `array()` but nothing. However, when I use invalid or not found action name for the key `action` such as `showAction` or `blah` it returns the following error:

```
Action 'showAcyoimn' was not found on handler 'poll'
#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher->_throwDispatchException('Action 'showAcy...', 5)
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\public\index.php(29): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#3 {main}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forward does not make HTTP redirect. More info here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html#forwarding-to-other-actions

If you want to redirect to other url use:

```
return $this->response->redirect(array(
  "controller" => "index",
  "action" => "actionName",
  "params" => "paramValues"
));
```

For example Forward is useful to show 404 page.